# Sending sms swift in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

If it possible to simulate sending sms in iPhone Simulator. I am not expecting to really send sms, just to show sms sending panel.

This is my code:

```
        if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {
            let messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
            messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self
            messageVC.recipients = ["1111111111", "2222222222"]
            messageVC.body = "hello phone"
            self.presentViewController(messageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("Not using messages")
```

It always just print `"Not using messages"`. Can someone advice, am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it is not possible to show sms sending panel in iOS simulator. You'll have to register for Apple's developer program and test that on the device.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking the same, but I needed confirmation.

Comment: There are a lot of articles describing this problem and like the simulator tells you it is `not using messages`